# marshall attributes inside XML elements with JAXB

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-data-jpa

I work with Spring JPA and have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.ENTITY_TABLE_PREFIX + "ENTRY")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "monObj_info")
public class EntryXML implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlAttribute
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ip_address", nullable = true)
    @XmlElement
    private String ip_address;

    @Column(name = "network_element_name", nullable = false)
    @XmlElement
    private String network_element_name;

    public EntryXML() {}

    public EntryXML(long id, String ip_address, String   network_element_name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.ip_address = ip_address;
        this.network_element_name = network_element_name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIp_address() {
        return ip_address;
    }

    public void setIp_address(String ip_address) {
        this.ip_address = ip_address;
    }

    public String getNetwork_element_name() {
        return network_element_name;
    }

    public void setNetwork_element_name(String network_element_name) {
        this.network_element_name = network_element_name;
    }

}
```

and the endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class EntryXMLEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private IEntryXMLService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/restxml", produces = { "application/xml" })
    public EntryXML findEntries() {
        EntryXML record = service.findById(1);
        return record;
    }

}
```

Now the requested response is:

```
<monObj_info id="1">
 <atribute name="ip_address" value="xx.xxx.xxx.x"/>
 <atribute name="network_element_name" value="xxxxxx"/>
</monObj_info>
```

Of course what I get is :

```
<monObj_info id="1">
  <ip_address>xx.xxx.xxx.x</ip_address>
  <network_element_name>xxxxxx</network_element_name>
</monObj_info>
```

I read similar posts , but the problem is I cannot create a List with the required elements inside my Entity Class, since it will not map with any column in the respective table, any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to create a data transfer object (DTO) that matches the requested XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal in a straight-forward but somewhat hackish way.

Since you don't want the `ip_address` and `network_element_name` properties
to be marshalled and unmarshalled directly, you need to remove their `@XmlElement` annotation
and add [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html).

Instead, you want some `<atribute name="..." value="..." />` elements marshalled and unmarshalled.
Therefore you need to add the following things to your `EntryXML` class:

- an `attributes` property holding a list of attributes.
  It is annotated with `@XmlElement` so that it will be part of XML marshalling and unmarshalling.
  It is annotated with [`@Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) so that it will **not** be part of database persistence.
- a simple helper class `Attribute` for holding name and value.
  `name` and `value` are annotated with `@XmlAttribute` so that they will be part of XML marshalling and unmarshalling.
- a [Marshal Event Callback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback) (*beforeMarshal*)
  for doing the conversion from `ip_address` and `network_element_name`
  to the `attributes` list.
- an [Unmarshal Event Callback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) (*afterUnmarshal*)
  for doing the opposite conversion.

---

```
@XmlElement(name = "atribute")
@Transient  // from package javax.persistence
private List<Attribute> attributes;

// there is no need for getAttributes and setAttributes methods

private static class Attribute {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")  // called by the unmarshaller
    Attribute() {
    }

    Attribute(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused") // this method is called only by the marshaller
private boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
    attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    attributes.add(new Attribute("ip_address", ip_address));
    attributes.add(new Attribute("network_element_name", network_element_name));
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused") // this method is called only by the unmarshaller
private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
    if (attributes != null) {
        for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            switch (attribute.name) {
            case "ip_address":
                ip_address = attribute.value;
                break;
            case "network_element_name":
                network_element_name = attribute.value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the XML output will look like this:

```
<monObj_info id="1">
    <atribute name="ip_address" value="xx.xxx.xxx.x"/>
    <atribute name="network_element_name" value="xxxxxx"/>
</monObj_info>
```

Comment: @sakis Glad to hear that. You should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
if it solved your question.